# Why blocks allocated for adjacent logical drive is not continuous?

Tags: linux

I issued a command 'fdisk -l',and noticed that the blocks allocated for adjacent primary partition is continuous.while blocks arranged for adjacent logical drive is not continous.For example,/dev/sda5 ends at 228331519,while /dev/sda6 starts at 228333568.

The following is my output:

```
[root@Toad cdrom]# fdisk -l
 
Disk /dev/sda: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes, 251658240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ac24a
 
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   190842879    94371840   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       190842880   207357951     8257536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       207357952   251658239    22150144    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       207360000   228331519    10485760   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       228333568   228743167      204800   83  Linux
```

Can someone tell me why?Thanks advance.

Comment: FWIW, that's a gap of _exactly_ 1 MiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition starts are often aligned to a "round" number (in computer terms!) to access them more efficiently. This is connected to the way in which the data is layed out on the hard disk, e.g. the start of a physical track.

Unless there is a huge amount of space wasted I would trust the program that made the partitioning and not worry about this.

Here is more info:

https://superuser.com/questions/225936/what-does-it-mean-to-align-partitions

Comment: [1MiB alignment is more for humans than for computers.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/disc-partition-alignment.html)  And you've missed the right answer, which is that they aren't contiguous because the old MBR partitioning scheme needs at least one sector (often two with some extensions to the scheme) between successive secondary partitions.

Comment: @JdeBP you need to update that, there are additional alignment recommendations for SSDs (see for example [this Intel guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-partition-alignment-tech-brief.html)).